# Infinite Scrolling in CorePlot

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-plot

Is there anyway that we could achieve infinite scrolling on a CorePlot Chart ?

I would like to load new set of data when user scrolls to the end of scatter plot , did some searching however nothing came up. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plot space delegate to monitor changes in the plot space. Insert plot data as needed when you reach the end of the current data set. You may also want to remove data points that are far outside the visible range to keep the plot data array from growing too large. Use the `-insertDataAtIndex:numberOfRecords:` and `-deleteDataInIndexRange:` methods to add and remove data, respectively, for better performance.

Comment: I hope I should be looking in to the callback  - (CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)proposedDisplacementVector; , Thanks for the tip

Comment: The [will change or did change](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_plot_space_delegate-p.html) methods are probably a better choice. These will be called any time the plot ranges change.